# Sort list by calculate value

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, lambda

I have a list of class A that have x and y value:

```
class A
{
   public int X { get; set; }
   public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

My List:

```
List<A> MyList = GetListOfA();
```

I want to sort the list by calculate value on A property. For example today dollar rate multiple by X.
If I will use OrderBy expression the method will be calculate x*log(x) times.

I found a few ways to do it like create internal class that include the value and the variable, Anonymous Type list that will include a list of the variable and calculated value, to add it to sorted dictionary by key of the calculated value etc.

What is the best approach to do it with clean and simple syntax?

Comment: Multiplying by a rate doesn't change the order (unless the rate is non-positive). Why not just sort by the original value without the multiplication?

Comment: Even if the rate is non-positive, this simply reverses the sorted order.

Answer (score 5):

> If I will use OrderBy expression the method will be calculate x*log(x) times.

No it won't. In LINQ to Objects, `OrderBy` projects each element to its ordering key once, and then compares those keys. For a collection of size `n`, there will be `n` accesses of the property, and then O(n log n) comparisons between those property values.

So basically, you should just use `OrderBy` to write the code as simply as you can - and trust that it will be reasonably efficient.

Comment: Absolutely correct! This behavior could be more clearly documented, though. I think maybe the Original Poster was confusing the LINQ `OrderBy` situation with the `Sort` method on `Array` and `List<>` where you can specify a `Comparison<>` delegate. As in the example `myList.Sort((x, y) => ExpensiveMethod(x, y, otherArgs))`. In that case if the `List<>` has count `n`, most certainly the delegate will have to be called more than `n` times. But that's a different situation.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: I agree it could definitely be more clearly documented... as is the case with various things around LINQ. (Some documentation is plain wrong...)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IComparer<T>` interface:

```
class A
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}

class AComparer : IComparer<A>
{
    public int Compare(A x, A y)
    {
        var fx = F(x);
        var fy = F(y);

        if (fx < fy) return -1;
        if (fx == fy) return 0;
        return 1;
    }

    double F(A a) // your calculation
    {
        return a.X * 1.2;
    }
}
```

And in your code:

```
var list = new List<A>();
// fill list
list = list.OrderBy(a => a, new AComparer()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend, that You do not change the list by itelf, treat it as immutable.

Keep a copy of this list, ( like a view ) , where all operations take place.

Encapsulate all in a new class.

I would do it like this.